# Every link_to on my rails 4 application is being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to

I'm experiencing some unusual behaviour with my Rails 4 Application. Every single-time I click on a link_to inside my views, my controllers actions are being called twice. For example:

In my `root_url` I have this standard call for `users_profile`:

```
<%= link_to('User Profile', users_profile_path, :class => "logout-button") %>
```

When I click this link, my console shows the following output:

```
Started GET "/users/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 20:45:53 -0200
Processing by Users::SessionsController#profile as HTML
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 45 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  InvestorProfile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "investor_profiles".* FROM "investor_profiles" WHERE "investor_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "investor_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  EmployeeProfile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "employee_profiles".* FROM "employee_profiles" WHERE "employee_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "employee_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  Rendered users/sessions/_investor_setup.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/profile.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started GET "/users/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 20:45:53 -0200
Processing by Users::SessionsController#profile as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 45 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  InvestorProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "investor_profiles".* FROM "investor_profiles" WHERE "investor_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "investor_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  EmployeeProfile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "employee_profiles".* FROM "employee_profiles" WHERE "employee_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "employee_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  Rendered users/sessions/_investor_setup.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/profile.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

People often have this behaviour when there's a remote (JS for example) calling the method, but this is not my case. the weirdest part is that, if I put the direct URL to the `users_profile_path` on my browser. I only get one request on my rails console:

```
Started GET "/users/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 20:48:17 -0200
Processing by Users::SessionsController#profile as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 45 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  InvestorProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "investor_profiles".* FROM "investor_profiles" WHERE "investor_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "investor_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  EmployeeProfile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "employee_profiles".* FROM "employee_profiles" WHERE "employee_profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "employee_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 45]]
  Rendered users/sessions/_investor_setup.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/profile.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 7.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

I'm getting this same result for every link inside my application, not only this one.

Comment: So there is absolutely no Javascript, are you sure? What happens in your unit test for the controller? Also try another browser see if it does the same thing.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure JS is not causing this behaviour. I tried with different browsers and all behave the same. I've been making a few changes and I believe Turbolinks gem is responsable for this.

Comment: Ok can you try without the gem and report back? It sounds like a client side issue of some sort though, as the web server received two requests. So Rails is doing the 'right' thing by calling your controller twice. P.S. Had a quick look and Turbolinks seems to me like it may generate javascript :-)

Comment: Can you add the controller in question? Maybe a `redirect_to` or `render` floating around?

Comment: As I predicted. Turbolinks was causing the behaviour and indeed it was a hidden JS problem within it. As soon as I removed it from my `application.js` the problem stopped. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @GuilhermeBarrosAvila Any news on how you managed to fix after removing `application.js`?

Comment: @RichPeck - funny to bump into you here on Stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Ditto - will email!!!

Comment: @RichPeck I just removed turbolinks gem from my `application.js`..
And I stopped receiving doubled requests.

Removed this line: `//= require turbolinks`

Comment: @RichPeck made an answer for my question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Turbolinks does actually improve efficiency with the http requests your app processes - you might want to try [JQuery Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) to see if that helps smooth things out! Thanks for getting back to me though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you would like your app to still make use of Turbolinks then "[Opting out of Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#opting-out-of-turbolinks)" on the code that is giving you problems is the way to go; just add `data-no-turbolink`.

I was having problems with using Bootstrap 3 and adding that fixed it. For example;

```
<li class="list-group-item" data-no-turbolink>
  <%= link_to download_path(item) do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 12):

Rails 5/6

When I was clicking on a link, the whole controller was being called twice. I tried the accepted answer, but it **does not work** for me, so I just set `turbolinks: false` as below:

```
<%= link_to("Demo", @user, data: { turbolinks: false } ) %>
```

Comment: For Rails 6, this solution works (as opposed to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to solve this on my own.
There's a default gem that is installed with rails 4.0, it is called [Turbolinks*](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/).

For some reason, the javascript used in this gem* was causing the doubled requests on my server. That's why only GET requests were behaving like this, and POST requests were normal.
I still don't fully understand why gem* causes that, but after I removed the following line from my `application.js` file, the doubled requests stopped.

```
=// require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to add `data-no-turbolink` to the  tag.

More info here: http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4