# Rails Controller Action being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, controller

In my rails app, I have a link so that a user can download a GIF on the site:

```
<%= link_to "gif", :controller => "projects", :action => :export_gif, :id => @project.id %>
```

This is the corresponding controller action:

```
def export_gif
    if @project.gif.blank?
      @project.generate_gif #this creates @project.gif
    end

    gif_path = @project.gif.gif_file_url
    gif_path.sub! 'https', 'http'
    send_data open(gif_path).read, filename: "project_#{@project.id}.gif", type: "image/gif"
  end
```

When the user clicks on the link, the export_gif action is being called twice.  How do I ensure that it only gets called once?

Here's what the logs look like after I click the link:

```
Started GET "/projects/38/export_gif" for ::1 at 2015-06-16 17:08:55 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#export_gif as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"38"}
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
  Gif Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "gifs".* FROM "gifs" WHERE "gifs"."project_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 38]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data project_38.gif (3.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 207ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/projects/38/export_gif" for ::1 at 2015-06-16 17:08:55 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#export_gif as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"38"}
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
  Gif Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "gifs".* FROM "gifs" WHERE "gifs"."project_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 38]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data project_38.gif (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 196ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: Not sure what the reason is for it being called twice, but you could add in some Javascript that disables the link once clicked?

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, please post the console or development.log output that indicates the method being called twice.

Comment: Sometimes Turbolinks causes this type of issues, perhaps can you try to add `data-no-turbolink` tag on your link.

Comment: are you running any script twice? such as jquery?  Make sure there is only one reference to it.  Look into your page's view source and double check scripts that are loaded.

Comment: @ConstantM that's an interesting idea, but I want to enable the user to click the button as many times as they'd like in case they close out the dialog window by accident.

Comment: @YannVERY Good call. At the moment, I support the turbolinks theory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205077/every-link-to-on-my-rails-4-application-is-being-called-twice.

Comment: I removed "//= require turbolinks" from application.js, and it stopped calling the action twice.  if you add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad the issue is resolved. Marking as duplicate.

Comment: The turbolinks suggestion was my issue. Once I added `"data-turbolinks": "false"` to my `link_to`, it solved my issue. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of `<img src="#">`. I had this in one of the files of layouts.
So I changed "#" with "http://example.com" and issue got resolved.

I got this solution from here(aNoble's answer):
[Rails seems to be serving the page twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786283/rails-seems-to-be-serving-the-page-twice)